# Safari: Why downloaded file is replaced automatically after downloading the same file again?

Tags: macos, safari

I do not know if I download another file with the same name but different contents will automatically replaced the old file.
Is there any setting of Safari to name the new file with an index like "filename-(1 or timestamp)"?

Comment: Are you sure that the filename is the same? Safari usually does not overwrite existing files (-1, -2 etc. is appended).

Comment: You might want to consider SuperUser. Stack Overflow is the wrong place for general computing questions. As your question is unrelated to programming, it's off-topic here...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank you for guiding me to the right site.